# Rigid Rotation of a Point Cloud

Tags: geometry, rotation

If I have a group of points that are aligned along some vector. For example:

```
points = Table[{i + 10 RandomReal[{-1, 1}], 
    i + 10 RandomReal[{-1, 1}], i + 10 RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}, {i, 1, 
    30, 0.5}];
points = Table[points[[i]] - Mean[points], {i, 1, Length[points]}];
```

How can I take advantage of the built in rotation functions to rotate it so that the long axis of the data is oriented along the vector {0,1,0}?

Answer (score 8):

Using `points` as given, you can use `RotationMatrix`,e.g. :

```
  Animate[Show[
  ListPointPlot3D[RotationMatrix[a, {0, 1, 0}].# & /@ points, 
   PlotStyle -> {Yellow, PointSize[0.02]}, 
   PlotRange -> Table[{-30, 30}, {3}], Background -> Black, 
   BoxRatios -> 1], 
  Graphics3D[{Red, Thickness[0.01], 
    Arrow[{{0, -30, 0}, {0, 30, 0}}]}]], {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

See comment below by @J.M.:

The rotation can be coded more directly using `RotationTransform`:, i.e.

```
RotationTransform[a,{0,1,0}]/@points
```

Comment: More directly, you can do `RotationTransform[a, {0, 1, 0}] /@ points`.

Comment: @J.M. thank you I will edit post. :)